# `svn st` for the root svn directory

Tags: svn, version-control

When I'm in a subdirectory of a subversion project, commands such as `svn st` will work only on the current working directory. For example:

```
$ svn co svn://example.com/trunk example
$ cd example
$ vi #editing files
$ svn st
M    base.c
M    s/inner.c
$ cd s
$ svn st
M    inner.c
```

I want that, as in `git` or `hg`, I'll be able to see the status of all the checked out project. I didn't find any option similar to `hg -C`, so that I'll be able to do:

```
$ svn -C ../
M    base.c
M    s/inner.c
```

Comment: If you prefer to use Git features but must use a Subversion server, I recommend [git-svn](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-svn.html).

Answer (score 0):

SVN doesn't have a notion of a project. It has directories and files, and you organize your project as you want in the repository. But SVN doesn't know that a particular directory is the root of a project.

You thus have to be in the right directory (or to pass it as an argument of `svn st`) to have all the changes of the project.

Comment: OK, then do I have anything parallel to `hg -C`, so that I can `svn -C $MyProj`?

Comment: `hg -C d args` is equivalent to `cd d && hg args && cd -`

Answer (score 0):

A simple workaround is defining `$BASE` to be the root checkout directory, and then using `svn st $BASE`. It wouldn't work when you're working on two subversion subdirectories.

I came up with the following bash script to do more or less what I was looking for, note the backticks surrounding the `pwd`:

```
$ cat svnb
#!/bin/sh
PREVDIR=`pwd`
while true; do
    if [ ! -d .svn ]; then break; fi
    PREVDIR=`pwd`
    cd ..
    if [ "`pwd`" == "$PREVDIR" ]; then break; fi
done
cd "$PREVDIR"
if [ -d .svn ]; then svn $@;
else echo Not in an version controlled directory
fi
```

Usage example:

```
$ cd example/s
$ svnb st
M    base.c
M    s/inner.c
$ cd / && svnb st
Not in an version controlled directory
```